# Arguments to open file

Tags: c, file

I want to open a file using the arguments when executing it, for example:

```
./Project 123.txt
```

I can make this work to some extent, but if I try to pass the arguments into a function, and then call the function, something is not working quite right.

Here is the function I have, which will read the lines from a text file:

```
int numeroLinhas(){
    int ch;
    FILE *fp;
    int linhas=0;
    fp = fopen("123.txt","r");
    while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF ){
        if(ch=='\n'){
            linhas++;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fprintf(stats, "linhas: %d\n", linhas);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    numeroLinhas();
}
```

So, I would like to know how can I pass the `argv[]` has an argument into my `numeroLinhas()` function, so that I don't have to call the name of the file at all during the coding, just when executing.

Comment: What does your textbook say on "arguments passing to a function" ?

Comment: Two things: Firs is that [`fgetc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an *`int`*. The second is that there already exist a function to read lines: [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

Comment: yes true, i changed the char ch to int. Yes, i am aware of fgets, but i must use fgetc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the name of the file to the function that counts the lines in the file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void numeroLinhas(const char *filename)
{
    int ch;
    int linhas = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s for reading\n", filename);
        return;
    }
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if (ch == '\n')
            linhas++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fprintf(stats, "linhas: %d no %s\n", linhas, filename);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        numeroLinhas(argv[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Error check `fopen()` calls; they fail.  Handle the `int` returned by `fgetc()` correctly.  Change the function to return `void` since there isn't a return.  Report errors on standard error.  Include file name in the outputs (error and routine).  Invoke the function on all arguments provided.  Don't say anything if no arguments are provided — or add `if (argc < 2) { fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file [...]\n", argv[0]); return 1; }` before the loop in `main()`.

<sup>Sorry about mixed English/Portugese messages.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have hard-coded the file name to open. Modify your function to take an argument, a string naming the file.

Then just pass the correct `argv` entry as the argument to the function, after checking the number of arguments to the program first.

Answer (score 1):

```
int numeroLinhas(char *filename){
   char ch;
   FILE *fp;
   int linhas=0;
   fp = fopen(filename,"r");
   while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF ){

        if(ch=='\n'){
        linhas++;
        }
   }

   fclose(fp);
   fprintf(stats, "linhas: %d\n", linhas);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
   //should have an if for argc size
   char *filename = argv[1];
   numeroLinhas(filename);
}
```

Comment: argv[1] will have a '\0' character, and you never directly deal with filename, so you don't need to keep track of size or anything. This should work fine.

Comment: Your commentary should be in the answer, not in a comment.  Strictly, you should either return a value from `numeroLinhas()` or change its return type to `void`.

Comment: ah i see, i was trying to pass filename has FILE *filename, and thats what i was doing wrong. Thank you for the help

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yes you are correct, it should indeed be void. Thank you for pointing it out